# How to fix irql_not_less_or_equal BSOD after installing new ram?

Tags: windows-7, memory, hardware-failure, bsod, reboot

Hey  everyone I'd be glad if anyone could help me out please.

My problem is with new ram I bought, my fujisto lifebook ah530 current ram that I've been using is Hynix HMT351S6BFR8C-H9 and the one I bought is skhynix hmt451s6bfr8a-pb.

I'd like to know what is causing the problem and if there is any way if I can fix it or not.

This BSOD only occurs when I just put the new ram, both of them will just restart the laptop after booting into windows loading screen and with the current one everything is fine on both slots working.

[image: Rams properties]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

IRQ_not_less_or_equal  BSOD is either a driver or hardware error. In this case, the old memory works, and the new memory causes the error above.

There is no Memory driver (not that I have seen), so the memory is incompatible with your computer.

You might try updating BIOS, but I am not sure this will correct the incompatibility .

You would need to go to a memory provider site that can tell you what memory to use. If the memory above is brand new, ask to return it for a refund or a replacement that is compatible with your machine.

Comment: How can I know if the memory is compatible with the motherboard?? I'm going to update my bios to see if there is any progress

Comment: If BIOS update works, that will be great. But if not then that means the memory is not compatible. Not working is why we can say that.

Comment: Although I can't find a compatible bios update ):

Comment: Ok I updated my bios but then again I put the new ram and a new bsod appears with bad pool header title

Comment: The thing is that bios recognize the memory but idk about the rest

Comment: It is incompatible with your motherboard / CPU and needs to be changed for compatible memory.

Comment: So I better get a 1333mhz

Comment: Yes getting compatible memory is a good idea. That is what I noted in my answer

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: So you should perhaps mark my answer as helpful to you.